# Soundcloud embed issues on Android 2.3

Tags: android, widget, soundcloud, android-2.3-gingerbread

Im having issues with the Soundcloud embed widget on Android 2.3 devices (Galaxy S1 for example)

Here is my example: http://jsbin.com/kedikile/1/

Firstly 90% of the time i get 'Oops we couln't find that track' secondly when it does appear, the widget floats at the top of the screen, it should be beneath the text

Comment: This question appears to be off topic because it is asking for help that should be asked of the Soundcloud support team.

Comment: soundcloud tech team respond to stack overflow questions tagged soundcloud see: http://developers.soundcloud.com/support